# How to invoke compiler with LD_PRELOAD in CMake

Tags: cmake, makefile, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, ld-preload

Is it possible to have CMake “export an environment variable” such as LD_PRELOAD before invoking the compiler/linker, like you could in a shell?

I am using an old 32-bit cross-compiler in WSL2. The source files are on Windows filesystem mounted into WSL, where the inodes are 64-bit thus not supported and cannot be read by the compiler.

```
cc1plus: error: /mydir/.../source.cpp: Value too large for defined data type
```

I followed instructions from [The 64 bit inode problem](https://www.mjr19.org.uk/sw/inodes64.html), and built inode64.so and manually verified it works with the 32-bit cross-compiler in a shell:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/mydir/.../inode64.so
arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ source.cpp
```

My question is, since I am building the project with CMake, how can I invoke ONLY the 32-bit compiler/linker from CMake with

```
LD_PRELOAD=/mydir/.../inode64.so
```

In my project build script, I tried export LD_PRELOAD before calling cmake, but it didn't work (because the 32-bit .so doesn't work with native 64-bit cmake tools?)

```
cmake ./
export LD_PRELOAD=/mydir/.../inode64.so
make install
```

```
ERROR: ld.so: object '/mydir/.../inode64.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32): ignored.
```

Comment: make a wrapper script and set that as your compiler?

Comment: @Peter thanks! I suppose that could work. But are you aware of a “proper” cmake way of doing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the variable `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER` to `env LD_PRELOAD=whatever.so`.  This will use the `env` command to launch the compiler.

The variable is used to initialize target properties, and of 3.25 supports generator expressions, so if you are using multiple compilers in the same build, you can wrap the env command in a test for compiler version or compiler name.

If instead you are using this compiler for all c++ builds in a particular configuration, just conditionally set the variable:

```
if(MY_CROSS_COMPILING_32_BIT)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER env LD_PRELOAD=whatever.so)
endif()
```

Comment: No need for `CACHE STRING "" FORCE`. Setting it as a normal variable will work. But you might want to make the condition `if (MY_CROSS_COMPILING_32_BIT AND NOT DEFINED CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_LAUNCHER)` to allow overriding it.

Comment: This worked! But I had to remove the quotes other wise I get error `/bin/sh: 1: 'env: not found`